# Sanity.io TypeError: undefined is not a function React Native Expo

Tags: javascript, react-native, sanity

I am trying to create a client with sanity.io and I keep getting the error - TypeError: undefined is not a function. I am following this YouTube video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AkEnidfZnCU&ab_channel=SonnySangha) and I am at 1:39:00. I have my sanity.js file

```
import { createClient } from "@sanity/client";

export const client = createClient({
    projectId: 'myprojectID',
    dataset: 'production',
    apiVersion: '2023-03-05',
    useCdn: true,
    token: process.env.TOKEN,
})

export default client;
```

When I try creating a query in my Homescreen.js I keep getting that createClient is not a function. I tried reinstalling sanity/client dependency.

```
import { createClient } from "../sanity";

const HomeScreen = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const [featuredCategories, setFeaturedCategories] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    client
      .fetch(
        `
        *[_type == "featured"] {
          ...,
        restaurants[]->{
          ...,
          dishes[]->
        }
        }
      `
      )
      .then((data) => {
        setFeaturedCategories(data);
      });
  }, []);
```

I know it's something to do with how I import the createClient because when I comment it out and the query request I get no errors. Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem but after some debugging I fixed it.
Firstly in your sanity.js dont use export const use
const client= createClient({.

And then in your homescreen.js use this-

```
import sanityClient from '../sanity';

const HomeScreen = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const [featuredCategories, setFeaturedCategories] = useState([]);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      headerShown: false,
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    sanityClient.fetch(
   
      `*[_type == "featured"] {
        ...,
        stores[]->{
          ...,
          services[]->,
        }
      }`
      ).then((data) => {
      setFeaturedCategories(data);
    });
  }, []);
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. You don‘t export `createClient` in ../sanity only `client`
2. You export client as default export and named export (shouldn‘t be a problem but unecessary)

Amend import from:

```
import { createClient } from "../sanity";
```

To:

```
import { client } from "../sanity";
```